# What is WaylandView?

Tags: qt, qml, qtwayland

I read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwayland-compositor-waylandview.html#details but still cannot understand what is WaylandView.
I tried to see how WaylandView works, but which type cannot be found.

```
WaylandView is not a type
```

I also tried [WaylandQuickItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwayland-compositor-waylandquickitem.html) which looks like the wrapper class of `WaylandView`. but cannot understand the difference, why make WaylandView registered in QML but cannot create the instance? What it is used for?

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: And did you add `import QtWayland.Compositor 1.15`?

Comment: @JarMan yes 5.15.1 and yes i imported

Comment: Ok, just checking. Unfortunately, I can't give a good answer for what `WaylandView` is, or why it doesn't recognize it. But `WaylandQuickItem` is a base for `ShellSurfaceItem`. It's the QML component you use to control where the wayland client gets displayed. You can see it used in the minimal compositor [example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwayland.git/tree/examples/wayland/minimal-qml/main.qml?h=5.15).

Answer (score 0):

`WaylandView` is mostly used if you are implementing a compositor in C++. In QML it's mostly an implementation detail, and `WaylandQuickItem` and `ShellSurfaceItem` wraps and uses it internally.

If you need to do something really specific that's incompatible with `ShellSurfaceItem` and `WaylandQuickItem` it could probably be useful, but otherwise it's safe to ignore it.

The QML cocumentation could probably have been better for that type ;)